# I want to be able to zoom in and out at the same time proportionally

Tags: d3.js

So I want to be able to zoom one thing out (my scale) and one thing in (my slider) so that when my slider that was on April of 2005 stays on April of 2005 even as the scale it is on zooms out to a broader perspective (like going from showing just 2005 to showing 2000-2010), the scale zooms out and the slider(which is a brush by the way) zooms in proportionally.

The difference between my problem and the [Brush and Zoom example](https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/34f08d5e11952a80609169b7917d4172)
is that I want the scale underneath to change, the graph over it to stay the same, and the brush to change proportionally to the scale change.

My problem is the event.transform object that I use to zoom, it gives me a K value and an X value that I can't figure out how to reverse engineer, is there any way around this?

Since someone wanted some code to look at:

```
function zoomScale() {
            let t = d3.event.transform;

            if(t) {
                xScale1.domain(t.rescaleX(xScale2).domain());
                context.select(".axis--x").call(xAxis2);
                context.select(".brush").call(brush.move, xScale2.range().map(t.invertX, t));
            }

        }
```

This makes the scale bigger AND the brush bigger, I want the brush to get smaller proportionally to how much bigger the scale gets.

Comment: Can you provide a fiddle/ plunkr with your code and what you've tried so far? Or an image of what you are trying to achieve? It's a bit unclear to me what you are trying to do.

Comment: I added some code if that helps

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok so I finally figured it out. Every time you have a selection on the scale you save it as a variable like in my case latestBrushDateSelection. You will also need a new TimeScale that saves the original domain of your axis, in my case xScale3. Then the Zoom function will look like this:

```
function zoomChart() {
            const t = d3.event.transform

            xScale2.domain(t.rescaleX(xScale3).domain())
            context.select('.axis--x').call(xAxis2)
            context.select('.brush').call(brush.move, latestBrushDateSelection.map(d => xScale2(d)))

        }
```